# Let $S$ be a subspace of Rn, $\dim(S) = k$, and $v_1,\dots,v_k \in S$

Tags: linear-algebra

Try to prove:

1. if $S = \operatorname{span}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$, then $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is a basis
2. if $v_1,\dots,v_k$ is linearly independent, then  $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is a basis

What I've done:

For the second one, $V =(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is a subset of a basis $B$ of $S$, Since $|V| = |B| = k$, $V=B$, thus $V$ is a basis of $S$. Is that correct?

Comment: Why did you change $\mathbb{R}^n$ to Rn?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis, then the proof for the second part is good.

For the first part, suppose that the set is not linearly independent (it is a set of generators by assumption). Then one of the vectors can be removed and the remaining set would still span $S$. Can you arrive to a contradiction?